# Creating report from excel data

Tags: excel, pdf, report

I want to pull data from multiple excel sheets and generate PDF report. Can you please suggest best way to do it? I am thinking of using Perl Excel & PDF modules. Will this work? or any other easy ways to achieve this same.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you want this done? There are an infinite number of possibilities that work. What language do you even want to use?

Comment: I am comfortable with Perl & PHP. Can I get it done easily with one of these? In addition to data from excel sheets, I may also want to include images and formatted text in the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe export sheets to csv and output PDF would be a more stable and fast way?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at Prawn http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/

It is a ruby gem. Once you have the data as ruby objects, using Prawn is super easy.